# how to avoid links to http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php hanging indefinitely

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-comments

We use Facebook comments and Facebook Like Buttons on our site.   These somehow generate a call to http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php which never loads, leaving the impression that the page isn't loading.   Is there a way to avoid having this script called?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways,

- write to Facebook and report the problem and suggest them to fix their Javascript
- download their Javascript code that add button to the page, fix it and directly link to it  from your server page.

Disadvantage of the last suggestion is that Facebook hosted Javascript code or back-end can be changed at any time and your old version of the script will not work.