# Facebook xd_arbiter.php error in JSON3

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We started getting an error from facebook's `xd_arbiter.php` file recently, I cant recall any changes made by us, so im starting to thinks the problem is at facebook.

This error happens in firefox 14.0.1, (chrome,safari,opera (latest versions)) seems to work fine.

The project is a facebook connect site, and we are using the js api.  We are basically using the same code as provided from facebook.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

The error only happens if the user is logged in to facebook prior to entering our site.
After the async load of the all.js file, we get this error.

```
JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal
```

in the `xd_arbiter.php?version=10`.  This is before the FB.init method is called.

I saw this post, but this does not help much, does it..

[how to avoid links to http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php hanging indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590850/how-to-avoid-links-to-http-static-ak-facebook-com-connect-xd-arbiter-php-hangi)

Can anyone confirm the they get this problem also, and confirm the the problem is at facebook.?

Thx for the help.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Did you get it resolved?

Comment: Can you post a URL where this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Any further updates on this ? Basically the Firebug script debug is not usable when there is a FB javascript as it will stop all the times on //connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=28

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar issue, but in `all.js` since yesterday (10/2/2012) in my Firebug debugging.
I test on Firebug 1.10.3 on Firefox 15.0.1 on Mac Lion.

Firebug shows this Javascript error in `all.js`:

```
JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal 
You can disable/enable break notifications in panel's tab menu.

Line 17:  (line 17 is super long - so I'm not putting it in here.  
          Somewhere in all.js:17 is a bad-control character I guess)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a controlled error which is done to feature test the JSON implementation. If you look at the source it is being caught in a try/catch and so should not be of any consequence. That

Chrome has two modes of debugging, one where it will stop on all errors, an one where it will only stop on uncaught ones - does not Firebug have something similar?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Firebug just tick ignore caught exceptions.
https://fbug.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=21640046000&name=breakOnExceptions.jpg&token=ABZ6GAdzSyyjuzEbxSTy6pOAnYp9FA0gZQ%3A1400670148851&inline=1